# PHP редирект через n секунд

Tags: redirect, html, php

Собственно вопрос в тайтле. Хочу найти аналог такого кода:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=http://google.ru"/>
```

для php, чтоб можно было послать через header(), либо что то похожее на это чтобы отработало даже если нет js, мета тег мне по своим причинам не подходит.

Comment: По каким-же? А те у кого javascript отключены еще не вымерли разве?

Comment: Ну все же есть % таких у которых нет js. Нет возможности изменить header в шаблоне.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ответ на поверхности. Все мета-теги с атрибутом `http-equiv` эквивалентны одноименным http-заголовкам.

```
header("refresh: 10; url=http://google.ru/");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sleep(10);
header('Location: http://google.ru');
exit;
```

Учтите, что php - серверный язык и задержку можно поставить только так.

Comment: Кстати - что касается php на сервере ( если предположить что это highload ), при таком подходе, многие пользователи будут ловить 502.
****
Правда это, скорее, проблема php а не подхода..

Comment: Такой вариант не совсем подходит. Наверно замучу промежуточную страницу через которую уже будут редиректить пользователей куда нужно.

Comment: Без тега meta и js?) Ну, хм, удачи, что ли)

Answer (score 1):

Может быть так ?

```
echo '<script>setTimeout(\'location="http://ya.ru"\', 10000)</script>';
```

Comment: > чтобы отработало даже если нет js

Comment: В таком случае нужен будет браузер.